# How to get text color from JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I am creating a simple RTF editor, I am using JTextPane component and RTFEditorKit. I want to get the color of the text entered in JTextPane. How can I get the text color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [getCharacterAttributes()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextPane.html#getCharacterAttributes%28%29):

```
AttributeSet attr = textPane.getCharacterAttributes();
Color color = (attr != null ? StyleConstants.getForeground(attr) : null);
```